# Set web.config for letsencrypt - Certify with Asp.NET Core and Angular 2 (Javascript-services)

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, lets-encrypt, certify

I am trying to install [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate with [Certify](https://certify.webprofusion.com/), but I get error, which (I think) has nothing to do with Certify. Problem is how my web.config is configured for handling my Asp.Net Core - Angular2 application.

I didn't configure web.config, [Javascript services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) did. On Certify web page writes at the bottom of page about my problem:

> I get the error "Automated checks for extensionless content failed.."
>   This means your web server configuration is not allowing files with no
>   extension to be served to site visitors. Unfortunately this is a
>   requirement of the Lets Encrypt service in order for it to fetch the
>   verification file which is automatically created within your site when
>   you request a certificate (more info).
>
> To help with this requirement we try to automatically configure this
>   for you. If you look in {your site}.well-known\acme-challenge you
>   will see we have created a web.config and a file called configcheck.
>   If you can't browse to this configcheck file in your web browser
>   (http://{your site}/.well-known/acme-challenge/configcheck then the
>   Lets Encrypt service can't access the files it needs either. You can
>   edit the web.config file in this folder to get extensionless files
>   working, then you can re-request your certificate. A mimeMap entry for
>   either "." or ".*" usually works depending on your operating system
>   version.

**Can some expert please help me correct my web.config file that will support whatever letsencrypt needs.** Currently anything inside .well-known/acme-challenge is not accessible via WebBrowser.

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Angular 2 pushState routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern=".*\.[\d\w]+$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(.well-known)" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(signin)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you.
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: `is not accessible via WebBrowser` is that like a 403? or 404?

Answer (score 17):

Put this in the `.\.well-known\acme-challenge\Web.Config` file just next to the Lets Encrypt DNS verification file(s). No need to change the `Web.Config` you already have. All it does it tell IIS to cough up files without extension in the directory where this `Web.Config` resides with mime type `text/plain` as Lets Encrypt expects that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="Either" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into with the default web.config in the acme-challenge folder was that the applicationhost.config contained:

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

The handlers section in the acme-challenge web.config therefore was not allowed with the result that the challenge failed. In this case the solutions were:
Change applicationhost.config line to:

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Or ...
Remove the handlers setting from the web.config in acme-challenge folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I forgot to remove App_Offline.htm while issuing the request. After removing it, the problem disappeared.